# Glassfish3: Same ear, different database

Tags: glassfish, ear

I want to deploy a EAR twice to the same Glassfishserver (To different Virtual Servers). But the Application uses a Databaseconnection, which is set with the `<jta-data-source>`-Tag in the Application. The Problem is now, that both Instances should use different Databases. 
Is there a way to set the `<jta-data-source>`-Tag on the Deployment?

Different Domains won't work, because they can't listen on the same port...

If it won't work, then I must use Apache in front of Glassfish to map the correct ports...

Comment: That should be possible. However it depends on the way you deploy (asadmin, IDE/Ant, ...)

Comment: I use the Webinterface (Port 4848). In detail I need a way to change the JDBC per Virtual Server. But I haven't found a way to do that...

Comment: I think this won't work since JDBC resources are domain wide. Do you have a chance to change your persistence.xml before deployment?

Comment: Yes. I can cahnge the persistence.xml for every deployment. But this isn't a nice way. Normaly the EAR should be build one time and then never be changed. The resources should be setup in the container. But currently this will allow only one Instance of the EAR in a domain and only one domain can listen on a port. This makes only one Instance of the EAR on a physical Webserver... This is somehow limiting the the server...

Comment: Can you make it configurable which id you look the database connection up with?

Comment: Yes. But how? And how can I set this during the deployment? A Tutorial would be good...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use application scoped resources. Just add a **glassfish-resources.xml** descriptor to your ear's META-INF. It should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="java:app/my-app-pool" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource"
                          pool-resize-quantity="1" 
                          max-pool-size="5" 
                          steady-pool-size="0"
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="60" >
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527" />
        <property name="dataBaseName" value="sun-appserv-samples" />
        <property name="User" value="APP" />
        <property name="Password" value="APP" />
        <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true" />
        <property name="driverType" value="4" />
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/my-app" pool-name="java:app/my-app-pool"/>
</resources>
```

After deploying your ear to the glassfish you can find your application in the configuration. There will be a tab "resources" where you can change all parameters.
So you can deploy as many application as you want and all of them could have different parameters.

There is a option to redeploy application "Preserving Application Scoped Resources". This option is available from Admin UI or from command line:

```
redeploy --name myapp --properties preserveAppScopedResources=true myapp.ear
```